# Reversing an array using a recursive function - .shift() question

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

This is a question I'm asking so I can understand the error I'm getting - please excuse the lack of knowledge and understanding I have.

I'm trying to write a recursive function that reverses an array. I have a function that reverses a string and I'm trying to reverse an array using a similar technique. I know there are a lot of ways to solve this but I'm keen to know why this doesn't work - obviously it's something to do with the .shift() method called on the input array.

Here is my code that reverses a string:

```
function revStr(str){
  if (str.length === 0) return "";
  return revStr(str.substring(1)) + str[0];
};
revStr("hello");
```

And here is my code I'm trying to use on an array:

```
function revStr(arr){
  if (arr.length === 0) return "";
  return revStr(arr.shift()) + arr[0];
};
revStr([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Why am I getting "arr.shift is not a function"?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift: *returns the removed element from the array; undefined if the array is empty*.

Comment: Not sure why you're not using [arr.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Comment: Thanks @sp00m, but when I use .shift() like this: 

    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let newArr = arr.shift();
    console.log(arr);

.shift() returns the other elements in the array, not the first. How can I incorporate it so it returns this?

Comment: "obviously it's something to do with ...."  This is your first mistake.  *Always* assume your code is the problem first.

Comment: Sorry @GeorgeJempty, I should have written "obviously it's something to do with... the way I've used...incorrectly". My code is obviously the problem otherwise it would have worked.

Comment: Thanks @tymeJV - but even if I'm using this incorrectly and it's only passing the first element of the array back in the loop, isn't it still an array, just one item?

Comment: It's the same as `array[0]`. You might want to use `.slice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work as you expected:

```
function revStr(arr){
  if (arr.length === 0) return "";
  var s = arr.shift();
  return revStr(arr) + s;
};
revStr([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```